# Why doesn't the HTMLVideoElement have the same constructor syntax as HTMLAudioElement?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, peerjs

I'm trying to make sense of why the [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) web API allows for use of `new Audio` but that [HTMLVideoElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement) does not have `new Video`.

For context, I'm working on a WebRTC project using the PeerJS library, and the 2nd last line of the code block below instantiates a "new Audio" object which we use to stream audio between peers. By extension, I thought that to stream and play video there would be a `new Video` available to use but it does not seem like it's even a thing (as demonstrated by console errors and validated by the absence of it in the HTMLVideoElement documentation). Why is that?

```
this.peer.on('call', (call)=>{
  console.log('recieving call');
  call.answer();
  call.on('stream', (mediaStream)=>{
    let clientAudio = new Audio(window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream));
    clientAudio.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Audio element this way:

`call.on('stream', (mediaStream)=>{
    let clientAudio = document.createElement('audio');
    clientAudio.autoplay = true;
    clientAudio.srcObject = mediaStream;
    // legacy way, dont use anymore
    // clientAudio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
}`

To answer your original question, try HTMLAudioElement and HTMLVideoElement. No idea why "Audio" is an alias to the former.